# How can I rescale images, which are represented as NumPy arrays, with Keras?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, numpy-ndarray

I'm using a built-in dataset, namely, [`CIFAR-10`](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html), with `Keras`. However, I need to rescale the input images in order to benefit from an existing model. In short, the input images are in `32x32x3`, and I need to rescale them to `299x299x3`. How can I rescale these images which are represented as `NumPy` arrays? Is there a practical way of doing this with `Keras` that provides a solution without the 'traditional' image processing approaches?

p.s. Software Stack:

- `Keras 2.3.1`
- `Python 3.7.3`

Comment: Keras' built in `keras.backend.resize_images` will not be able resize your images from 32 to 299 as it takes an integer scale value. Are you open to using `PIL` or `cv2`? I know that's not what you're asking for, but unfortunately from what I understand you won't be able resize to the exact size you're looking for using Keras, at least not cleanly.

Comment: I'm using both of them. Between, as I mentioned in the OP, the images are represented as NumPy arrays, so no problem with integer values though.. @MZ

Comment: No no, what I meant by integer is the fact that keras can **only** scale by an integer scale. So 2x and 3x but no 2.5x. You're best bet is to use the `cv2.resize` function, maybe wrapped in a `numpy.vectorize` function.